# Microsoft Certified Partner - Report

Tags: licensing

Does anyone know a way to report a company claiming to be a "Microsoft Certified Partner" when they aren't?

Or a way to truly check if they are or not?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Microsoft?

Comment: Not sure what channel I should go through.  Email?  Phone Number?

Comment: For people reading this, you need to call 1-800-RU-LEGIT.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of partner are they claiming to be? The Microsoft Partner Program is available to just about everyone and it doesn't take much (at all) to become a Registered Member of the Microsoft Partner Program.

Comment: I am fairly sure they are not what they are claiming to be (they have little to no software development or technical experience).  Is there a list of registered members on a site somewhere that I can look up?  I can't find them on here: https://partner.microsoft.com/US/30000104?ID=91160884

Comment: What is it exactly that they're claiming to be?